# On Kadec norms definition.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

So I have this definition of Kadec norm  
                                                                             
  $\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $(X,\|\|)$ be a Banach space. The norm $\|\|$ is said to be a Kadec norm if $x_n \xrightarrow{w} \bar{x}$ and $\|x_n\|\to \|\bar{x}\|$ implies $x_n\to \bar{x}.$  
 
 I was wondering why is it necessary in this definition that $X$ to be a Banach space. I though that it is not at all, and that then the condition would imply that $X$ is Banach. But I was not able to prove that statement. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for $X$ to be a Banach space. For example in Megginson's *An introduction to Banach space theory*, the Kadets-Klee property is defined for normed spaces (Definition 2.5.26, pg. 220). The same page also provides examples of non Banach spaces which have the Kadets-Klee property:

By a Theorem of Kadets (1959) which is mentioned without proof in the end of this page, every seperable normed space has an equivalent locally uniformly rotund norm. A theorem by Vyborny (1956) states that locally uniformly rotund spaces have the Kadets-Klee property (see Theorem 5.3.7, pg. 463 in the same book). 
Combining these two theorems, you have that every seperable normed space has an equivalent Kadets norm.